# calendar different between 2 dates

Tags: shell-script, shell, date

Convert your days alive to use dialog command and a calendar for date of birth select and current date

Hint:

```
dialog --stdout --title "Today" --calendar "today" 0 0 0 0 0 | awk -F/ '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }'
```

Also add
You have been alive X years(s) Y days(s) Z hour(s) A minute(s) B second(s)
thats what I have but I keep getting errors from reading the date from dialog 
(Date entered: .
^[[M#<6)

```
#!/bin/bash
#daysalive
#using hard coded date calc days between two days date 
: ${DIALOG=dialog}

USERDATE=`$DIALOG --stdout --title "CALENDAR" --calendar "Please choose a date..." 0 0` | awk -F/ '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }'

case $? in
  0)
    echo "Date entered: $USERDATE.";;
  1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  255)
    echo "Box closed.";;
esac


DOBDATE=$($USERDATE \+%S)
NOWDATE=$(date +%s)
echo -n "daysalive"
DAYSALIVE="$(($NOWDATE- $DOBDATE)" / 86400 )
echo $DAYSALIVE
```

Comment: You say you're getting errors. What are these errors?

Comment: Date entered: 27/09/2005.
daysalive: line 18: 27/09/2005: No such file or directory
daysalivedaysalive: line 21: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
daysalive: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: i have seen that post but the problem with reading the date from the dialog

Comment: its show me this error now Date entered: .
^[[M#<6

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of how to calculate number of days between 'now' and a date retrieved from the user by 'dialog' is correct, but the script has a lot of mistakes and errors like unmatched quotes, omitted commands, uppercase `S` where it should be lowercase `s` and so on.

Anyway, here's the script with errors fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#daysalive

: ${DIALOG=dialog}

USERDATE=$($DIALOG --stdout --title "CALENDAR" --calendar "Please choose a date..." 0 0 | awk -F/ '{ print $2"/"$1"/"$3 }')

case $? in
  0)
    echo "Date entered: $USERDATE.";;
  1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  255)
    echo "Box closed.";;
esac


DOBDATE=$(date --date $USERDATE +%s)
NOWDATE=$(date +%s)
echo -n "daysalive"
DAYSALIVE=$(( (NOWDATE - DOBDATE) / 86400 ))
echo $DAYSALIVE
```

Comment: thank you for answer i still have to calculate  X years(s) Y days(s) Z hour(s) A minute(s) B second(s) but the script working thank you again

Comment: thank u guys for your help i am done with it  thank you Hkoof for your help